# Why VS automatically adds call to base class virtual method?

Tags: c#, inheritance, virtual

Having code like this:

```
class X
{
    public virtual void Test()
    {
    }
}

class Y : X
{
    public override void Test()
    {
        base.Test()   //added automatically, why?
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Because, by implication, that won't break anything.

Comment: why would it be annoying if nothing breaks?

Comment: Not really, much of the time you will have a need to extend a method's functionality and will end up calling `base.Method()` in the overridden method.

Comment: That's often not the case. You may want to make it an abstract method to force inheriting classes to implement it.

Answer (score 3):

Because in most of the cases it makes sense or is even required to call the base class implementation, e.g. virtual `Dispose` methods (base class needs to be Disposed) or virtual  `OnXXX` methods in WinForms (base class usually fires an event from their `OnXXX` methods).

Of course if the virtual method is yours and you do not want this behavior I agree that it's pretty annoying ;)

Comment: Annoying or not, even your own base methods may change - with some potentially _good stuffs_ going.

Comment: Sure, but there may also be cases where it is intended to not use the functionality of the base class. Take `Object.ToString` as one example where you usually don't need the base implementation.

Comment: Exactly; this is the reason I find 'annoying' a bit harsh for a 50 / 50 toss at intended behaviour.